# Windows 10 File Explorer Taskbar Icon disappeared

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, taskbar, icons

Okay I have a weird one for you and I'm lost on where to go, what to edit, etc. My Girlfriend's Windows 10 No longer has a File Explorer Icon when the application is open and running. The last icon is the icon I'm looking to fix. As you can see from the screenshot I've looked in regedit for an obvious error or something.

My google fu has also had me rebuild the icon cache, but to no avail. I'm open to any and all suggestions at this point.

Thanks guys.

[image: The icons]

Comment: normally clearing the icon cache fixes it. try it again, maybe you missed a step

Comment: I'll re-try to rebuild the cache again but at this point, nothing has changed.

Comment: Still no changes

Comment: which guide have you followed?

Comment: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5645-icon-cache-rebuild-windows-10-a.html#option2